# extension for convex sets in $W^{1,p}$ spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

> Show that every convex quadrilateral $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ admits an
> extension operator $P:W^{1,p}(K)\to W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ . Deduce
> the same property for any triangle $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ .

There is a result that if we consider two open sets $A_1,A_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and define a $C^1$-bijection $H:A_2\to A_1$ by $x=H(y)$ , then for $u\in W^{1,p}(A_1)$ one has $u\circ H\in W^{1,p}(A_2)$ , provided $\displaystyle\frac{\partial H_i}{\partial y_j}\in(L^\infty(A_2))^4$ for $i,j=1,2$ and $H=(H_1,H_2)$ .

I suspect that this correspondence between these two arbitrary open sets the assertion above can be proved for any convex quadrilateral , but I don't get any closer .

Any help is appreciated . Regards .

Comment: This results holds for any bounded $K$ provided that its boundary is Lipschitz. The proof can be found in most introductory PDE books

Comment: Do you need more specific results that apply to your particular shapes?

Comment: Yes , I'd love to .